# How to validate a selected radio button in a quiz system using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am preparing a quiz app using php and mysql. I having a problem validating a radio button.

When I click on check button it only checks whether the first option is correct or not but actually it should check the selected option in a radio button is correct or not.

The code I have used is here:

```
$singleSQL = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id='$question' LIMIT 1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($singleSQL)){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $thisQuestion = $row['question'];
    $type = $row['type'];
    $subject =$row['subject'];
    $exam =$row['exam'];
    $explan =$row['explan'];
    $question_id = $row['question_id'];
    $s ='<strong>'.$subject.'</strong>';
    $e ='<small>'.$exam.'</small>';
    $q = '<h2>'.$thisQuestion.'</h2>';
    $ex ='<div id="welcomeDiv" style="display:none;" class="expl" >'.$explan.'</div>';
    $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM answers WHERE question_id='$question' ORDER BY rand()")or die(mysql_error());

    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){
        $id2=$row2['id'];
        $answer = $row2['answer'];
        $correct = $row2['correct'];      
        $answers .= '<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                     <tr>
                    <td class="chk">
                    <label style="cursor:pointer;">
                    <input type="radio" name="rads" value="'.$correct.'">'.$answer.'</label></td>
            </tr>
                </table>
        <input type="hidden" id="qid" value="'.$id.'" name="qid"><br />';

    $result=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM answers WHERE question_id='$question' ");
    $nrows=mysql_num_rows($result);
    for($i=0;$i<=4;$i++){
        if (isset($_POST[$correct])) {
            $answer= $_POST[$correct];
        }

        if($answer&&$correct==1){
            echo $dv.='<div style="display:none;" class="green" id="chek" >Your answer '.$answer.'  is correct</div>';
        } else {
            echo $dv2.='<div style="display:none;" class="red" id="chek" >Your answer '.$answer.'  is worng</div>';}
        }
```

i have two tables one is questions and anothher is answers

questions table

```
            id question_id question 
             1  1          question1
```

answers table

```
            id questions_id answer correct
            1       1        op1    1
            2       1        op2    0
            3        1       op3    0
            4        1       op4    0
```

Comment: Without the HTML markup, this is a cylinder head with no valves.

Comment: You should not need the 2 inner queries, that is really bad in fact.

Comment: Suggestion, [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: for clarity, what does your table look like?

Comment: @Strawberry i have edited my question with table structure plz help me

Comment: every one who view your html source will know all the answers.

Comment: name="rads" is your problem you should have unique name for every group of answers

Answer (score 0):

name="rads" is the problem you should have unique name for every group of answers.

you should add something like this:

```
$i = 1;
 while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){
        $id2=$row2['id'];
        $answer = $row2['answer'];
        $correct = $row2['correct'];      
        $answers .= '<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                     <tr>
                    <td class="chk">
                    <label style="cursor:pointer;">
                    <input type="radio" name="rads_'.$i.'" value="'.$correct.'">'.$answer.'</label></td>
            </tr>
                </table>
        <input type="hidden" id="qid" value="'.$id.'" name="qid"><br />';
$i++;
```